# How to manage filesystem quota in Dart 1.5?

Tags: dart

In older versions of dart, there used to be function

```
window.storageInfo.requestQuota(Window.PERSISTENT, quota)
```

On top of that, there used to be function to get the report:

```
queryUsageAndQuota
```

I can see that StorageInfo class has been renamed to DeprecatedStorageInfo, and is no longer available via window.storageInfo.

How can I access this functionality?
I get Quota exceeded errors, although I increased the value passed to:

```
window.requestFileSystem(quota, persistent: true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Chrome is in the process of migrating to [W3C Quota management API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/quota/raw-file/tip/Overview.html)

see also

- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=332325
- http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink/trunk/LayoutTests/storage/quota/storagequota-request-persistent-quota.html?pathrev=165920

but it seems this has not yet fully landed in Dartium.

The object returned by

```dart
window.navigator.storageQuota
```

has no usable methods.

Answer (score 2):

In Dart 1.6, DeprecatedStorageInfo is available with

```
DeprecatedStorageQuota sq = window.navigator.persistentStorage;
```